# Removing same columns across tables in R

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to remove same columns from multiple tables.

I've tried this

```
lapply(list(formc02, formc01, formc03, formc04), function(x) x <- select(x,-c(ProgramAlias,create_date, ActivityAlias)))
```

The results just showed in the console but the tables didn't change....Hope anyone could help. Many thanks.

Comment: Try `lapply(list(formc02, formc01, formc03, formc04), function(x) select(x,-c(ProgramAlias,create_date, ActivityAlias)))`

Comment: The function cannot change `x` (or rather it can change it but it does not have any impact outside the function) because `x` is a local variable. The function must _return_ the updated tables (it already does because assignment returns the assigned value invisibly, this is what you see in the console) and you must store the results.

Comment: @Sotos The tables didn't change neither...

Comment: @antoine-sac how can I do that??

Comment: Did you assign it? `your_list <-lapply(...)`... Also, have a look at the target I duped it with.

Comment: You may still be confused by the answers in the duplicate because they don't say explicitly that you have to store the results of the `lapply` into an updated list. Running `lapply(mylist, ...)` does NOT update `mylist`, you have to assign the results with `mylist <- lapply(mylist, ...)`.

Comment: to summarise the comments above. do `list_df <- list(formc02, formc01, formc03, formc04)` and then use `list_df[] <- lapply(list_df, function(x) select(x,-c(ProgramAlias,create_date, ActivityAlias)))`

Comment: Thanks all. However, even though I assigned it to the list, the list changed but the tables still not change....